# getting NameError with beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I am working with bs4 at the command line:

```
>>> listing.find("a",{"data-oname": "result"})
<a data-consolidated-tab="false" data-oname="result" href="xxx">3 yyy</a>
>>> a =listing.find("a",{"data-oname": "result"})
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PyCharm 3.4.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_exec.py", line 3, in Exec
    exec exp in global_vars, local_vars
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

why is this happening?

Comment: That looks like a PyCharm issue, not a BeautifulSoup one.

Comment: No idea *why* PyCharm is failing here, but clearly `listing.find()` returns an object, and assigning that to `a` should Just Work™. This certainly would work in the Python interactive interpreter, but if this doesn't work in the PyCharm console, then that's a problem with that console.

Comment: "a =..." is there really a space ? :)

Comment: Does `a` appear in the output of `globals()` ?

Comment: @Mejmo: Whitespace would make no difference there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I know, my comment was about possible weird character (ord <> 32) that could look like space :) In Python 3.x also non-ascii variable names were introduced.

Comment: @Mejmo: that'd raise a syntax error. There are no valid identifier characters even in Python 3 that'd look like a space.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this guys.